# Need to change string to date

Tags: php

I have some timing strings like,

```
$timing_strings =array(1=>'just now', 2=>'3 minutes ago', 3=>'3 weeks ago');
```

The question is i want to change that type of strings into particular date-time format. How can i do this..? I need an output like,

```
array(
1=>'2013-10-04 06:24:24',
2=>'2013-10-04 06:21:24',
3=>'2013-09-14 06:24:24'
);
```

I couldn't get any solution for this, any ideas appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate problems: parsing string to date and converting your values.

Parsing string to date ultimately is a complex problem.
`strtotime` and `DateTime` can parse most date formats, but not all.
They won't parse "just now", for example.
You can extend that with your own hardcoded values, of course.

Converting values, though, is simple:

```
array_map(
    function ($dateString) {
        if ($dateString === 'just now') {
            $dateString = 'now';
        }
        return (new DateTime($dateString))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    },
    $timing_strings
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to convert most time strings with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: is it possible to convert strings like `just now` using `strtotime`

Comment: It should be, I linked to the documentation. Not all strings work though

Comment: okay...then i think i need to write some conditions for extracting words like now, week, etc then change it with `strtotime`..am i right...???

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?
$timing_strings =array(1=>'just now', 2=>'3 minutes ago', 3=>'3 weeks ago');
foreach ($timing_strings as $time){
    if ($time == 'just now') $time = 'now';
    $arrTime[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($time));
}

print_r($arrTime);
?>
```

[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/pB5BmU80)

Comment: @SherinJose The pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 0):

used this code:

```
<?php

$timing_strings =array(1=>'just now', 2=>'3 minutes ago', 3=>'3 weeks ago');
$new_arr=array();
foreach ($timing_strings as $time) {
    $new_arr[]  = check_time($time);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
echo "</pre>";
exit;

function check_time($time) {
    if (strpos($time,'just now') !== false) {
        return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('now'));
    }elseif (strpos($time,'minutes ago') !== false) {
        return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-'.(int)$time.' minutes'));
    }elseif (strpos($time,'weeks ago') !== false) {
        return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-'.((int)$time*7).' days'));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-10-04 18:47:44
    [1] => 2013-10-04 18:44:44
    [2] => 2013-09-13 18:47:44
)
```